# How can I force maven to resolve a variable's literal value in the pom it is used in?

Tags: maven, variables, lazy-evaluation, resolve

It seems that `Maven` doesn't resolve variables until they are used in the `child pom`. This means that variables inherited from a parent like `${basedir}` are incorrect when used by the child. For example, I have:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>lib</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

in my parent `pom` (because I'm using `jars` that haven't been pushed to any `maven` repo and I don't want to host my own).

I have a directory called `'mavenrepo'` in my project root. However, when a child attempts to resolve this repo, the variable `${basedir}` now points to the child project's directory and not the parent's base dir.

**How can I force `maven` to resolve the `${basedir}` to point to the directory that contains the parent `pom`?**

Answer (score 0):

The best i can suggest is to use a repository manager like Artifactory, Nexus or Archiva. Nexus has a very simple setup and makes life easier in particular if you have artiacts which not available via Central or other repositories.

In this relationship i can recommend to read [Stephen Connolly blog about such kind of problem.](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/03/playing-trade-offs-with-maven.html)

Apart from i would recommend to use [Stephen Connolly's non-maven-jar-maven-plugin](https://github.com/stephenc/non-maven-jar-maven-plugin) which should help in such situations.

Comment: Hi - the local repository works just fine. An enterprise maven repo isn't an option because we don't have an 'enterprise' yet... My question was regarding how Maven lazily resolves the values of project variables. Do you have any advice on that?